# On-premise multi-zone Kubernetes federation cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, federation

Let's say I have *baremetal servers* at **New York, London, Delhi, Beijing.** My requirement is to join all the 4 baremetal servers in a distributed environment and run services on top of kubernetes. ***How do I achieve this ?***

Comment: This is far too broad a question. This involves knowledge of your network architecture, your application architecture, what services you want to deploy. Please add more information

Comment: @jaxxstorm Let's saw I want to deploy a simple Mysql service. What more information must I provide ?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? How will your MySQL be accessed? Where is your app located? Where is the data located? You're trying to condense complex, multi region system design and architecture into a stackoverflow question. This is way too broad a question.

Answer (score 3):

Question is too broad but here's my take with insights on a global datastore:

Option 1: Setup a K8s cluster for each region and have them talk to each other through services. Have each talk to their own datastores, and keep data separate per region an use something like [GSLB](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/11-1/gslb/how-gslb-works.html) to route your traffic.

Option 2. Setup a K8s cluster for each region and use a global database like [Dynamdb Global Tables](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/), [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/) or [CosmosDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/cosmos-db/).

Option 3. Use [Kubernetes Federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/). Federation doesn't necessarily solve the multi-region data store challenge, and it's also in Beta as of this writing. However, it will help manage your Kubernetes services across multiple regions.

Option 4. Something else, that you create on your own, fun! fun!

Comment: Thanks Rico..But can you please confirm whether we need to set up k8 master in each region as you have mentioned in option 1.